# Who invok's a nested function in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, object, scope

Just trying to clear some misconceptions...

```
function outer(){
    function inner(){

    }
}
```

1. Does a function being a member of a particular object decides it's contextual this ?
2. Like, is it the reason that outer function is member of window object therefore the contextual this of outer function refers to window object ?
3. If yes then whos member is the inner function ?
4. Is inner member of outer function's object ?
5. And why the inner function's contextual this is referring to the window object ?
6. Is any function(global or nested) invoked without new operator will have contextual this referring to window object ?

Comment: [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Answer (score 0):

For an ordinary function (that is, not an arrow or member function), `this` is populated dynamically, at the call time. `this` depends on how the function is being called, not on where it's been declared.

`this` can be populated by 1) a property accessor (`object.func`) or 2) `new` as in `new func()` or 3) an indirection like `call/apply`. If the engine cannot populate `this` for a particular function call, it's set to the global/window in the sloppy mode and `undefined` in the strict mode. This applies to both global and inner functions.

Global functions being members of the global/window is an orthogonal concept and doesn't affect `this` in any way.

Inner functions, like local variables, are not members of any object.